# Calling caspol.exe

Tags: wpf, xbap

I'm deploying an xbap application that runs as a full-trusted app.
To get permissions on each client, I'm currently running a batch file that just calls `caspol.exe`.

It basically just does this:

```
%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\caspol -m -ag 1 -url "http://127.0.0.1/mypath/*" FullTrust -exclusive on
```

This works fine.
However, I realized that caspol.exe ships with the .NET SDK (as does the .NET Framework Control Panel applet) and *not* with the .NET runtime.
So, if I'm installing on a client machine that only has the runtime and not the SDK, how do I do it?

Can this be programatically done?
Are there any configuration settings that I can direct people to use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The caspol utility is actually included with the .NET redistributable package for .NET 2.0.  As long as the PC has .NET 2.0 installed, you can rely on caspol being there.  The SDK is not required.

On a side note, starting with .NET 2.0, the .NET configuration utility in the Control Panel is available exclusively with the 2.0 SDK and does not come with the redistributable package.

-Ken